Populating a drop down menu in Python with audio hardware channels
I have written a single channel vu meter App in Python on my Mac.  It has a drop down menu to set the audio source which is a Scarlett 2i2 USB and then another drop down menu to set either channel 1 or 2 of that hardware.  It dynamically looks for the hardware and channels of any hardware on or connected to the Mac.  I am now trying to make a multi channel version, I have created a separate class for the view to make creating multiple versions of the same vu view but this has introduced errors which I am struggling to solve.  I have been able to populate the first drop down menu with available audio hardwares sources but my second drop down menu also populates with the available audio hardware sources not the channels available for the selected hardware.  Here is my code.
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import queue
from tkinter import StringVar

CHUNK = 2048
FORMAT = pyaudio.paFloat32
RATE = 48000
QUEUE_SIZE = 10

class ChannelView:
    def __init__(self, master, channel_index, input_devices):
        self.master = master
        self.channel_index = channel_index
        self.input_devices = input_devices
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

        # Input dropdown specific for this channel
        self.input_var = StringVar(master)
        self.input_var.set("Select Input")
        self.source_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(self.frame, self.input_var, self.input_var.get(), *[], command=self.change_source)
        self.source_menu.pack(side="top", padx=10, pady=5)

        self.vu_meter_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, width=100, height=300, bg='black', highlightthickness=0)
        self.vu_meter_canvas.pack(pady=20)

        # VU meter representation
        self.vu_meter = self.vu_meter_canvas.create_rectangle(0, 300, 100, 300, fill='green')

        self.peak_label = ttk.Label(self.frame, text="Peak: 0 dB")
        self.peak_label.pack()

        # Start button
        self.start_button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Start", command=self.toggle_audio)
        self.start_button.pack(pady=5)

        # Solo button
        self.solo_button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Solo Off", command=self.toggle_solo)
        self.solo_button.pack(pady=5)

        # Initialize flags
        self.is_running = False
        self.is_solo = False
        self.audio_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=QUEUE_SIZE)
        self.channel_device_index = None

    def change_source(self, selection):
        self.channel_device_index = next((device[0] for device in self.input_devices if device[1] == selection), None)
        print(f"Channel {self.channel_index + 1} selected source: {selection}")

    def update_sources(self):
        menu = self.source_menu['menu']
        menu.delete(0, 'end')
        for device in self.input_devices:
            menu.add_command(label=device[1], command=lambda value=device[1]: self.input_var.set(value))
        self.input_var.set("Select Input")  # Reset the default value

    def update_vu_meter(self, peak_db):
        peak_db = max(min(peak_db, 0), -60)
        height = (peak_db + 60) / 60 * 300
        self.vu_meter_canvas.coords(self.vu_meter, 0, 300 - height, 100, 300)

        color = 'red' if peak_db > -3 else 'yellow' if peak_db > -10 else 'green'
        self.vu_meter_canvas.itemconfig(self.vu_meter, fill=color)
        self.peak_label.config(text=f"Peak: {peak_db:.1f} dB")

    def toggle_audio(self):
        if self.is_running:
            self.is_running = False
            self.start_button.config(text="Start")
            # Logic to stop audio processing here
        else:
            self.is_running = True
            self.start_button.config(text="Stop")
            # Logic to start audio processing here
            
    def toggle_solo(self):
        self.is_solo = not self.is_solo
        self.solo_button.config(text="Solo On" if self.is_solo else "Solo Off")

class AudioMeter:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Audio VU Meter")
        master.geometry("800x700")  # Increased height for more channels
        master.configure(bg='black')

        self.input_devices = self.get_input_devices()
        self.channels = []

        # Add button to add new channels
        self.add_channels_button = ttk.Button(master, text="Add Channels", command=self.add_channel)
        self.add_channels_button.place(x=10, y=40)  # Position at the top-left (nw)

        # Dropdown for global input device selection
        self.global_input_var = StringVar(master)
        self.global_input_var.set("Select Global Input Device")
        self.global_input_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(master, self.global_input_var, self.global_input_var.get(), *[], command=self.select_global_input)
        self.global_input_menu.place(x=10, y=10)  # Position to the right of the button

        # Populate the global input device dropdown with the available devices
        self.populate_global_input_menu()

    def get_input_devices(self):
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        input_devices = []
        for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
            device_info = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
            if device_info['maxInputChannels'] > 0:
                input_devices.append((i, device_info['name'], device_info['maxInputChannels']))
        p.terminate()
        return input_devices

    def populate_global_input_menu(self):
        menu = self.global_input_menu['menu']
        menu.delete(0, 'end')
        for device in self.input_devices:
            menu.add_command(label=device[1], command=lambda value=device[1]: self.global_input_var.set(value))
        self.global_input_var.set("Select Global Input Device")  # Set the default prompt

    def add_channel(self):
        # Create a new channel view
        channel_index = len(self.channels)  # Index based on current number of channels
        channel_view = ChannelView(self.master, channel_index, self.input_devices)
        channel_view.frame.pack(side="left")  # Stack channels horizontally
        channel_view.update_sources()  # Populate input sources for this channel
        self.channels.append(channel_view)  # Add new channel view to the list

    def select_global_input(self, selection):
        print(f"Global input device selected: {selection}")
        # Logic for handling selected global input here
        # Optionally update each channel's source menu
        for channel in self.channels:
            channel.update_sources()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AudioMeter(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


What do you want to populate into the second dropdown? A list of numbers, i.e. 1, 2, etc?

I want the available inputs from the audio input hardware.  Input 1 or Input 2

Where can these items be retrieved?
